# I'm having trouble understanding Android MasterKeyBuilder and custom aliases

Tags: java, android, android-keystore

I am wanting to use a MasterKey to encrypt a file on my Android device, and am a little uncertain on what the correct way is of doing that.  The following code works fine across reboots, but I want to make sure the Masterkey won't change on me in the future (For example, after an Android update).

```
MasterKey masterKey = new MasterKey.Builder(context)
                    .setKeyScheme(MasterKey.KeyScheme.AES256_GCM)
                    .build();
 EncryptedFile encryptedFile = new EncryptedFile.Builder(
                    context,
                    privateKeyFile,
                    masterKey,
                    EncryptedFile.FileEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM_HKDF_4KB
            ).build();
```

According to the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/security/crypto/MasterKey.Builder), the MasterKey.Builder constructor does accept a custom alias, but when I try to do this, I get this exception when trying to build the `encryptedFile` object.

```
MasterKey masterKey = new MasterKey.Builder(context,"myAlias")
                    .setKeyScheme(MasterKey.KeyScheme.AES256_GCM)
                    .build();

            // this lets us encrypt the private key file with the master key
            EncryptedFile encryptedFile = new EncryptedFile.Builder(
                    context,
                    privateKeyFile,
                    masterKey,
                    EncryptedFile.FileEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM_HKDF_4KB
            ).build();
```

exception: `com.google.crypto.tink.shaded.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).`

My thinking was if I pass my own alias in, the `MasterKey.Builder` would use this to always generate the MasterKey the same way, rather than depending on some 'magic' that may or may not change in the future.

According to the answer in [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/leqma3/need_help_understanding_masterkeybuilder/), I should be fine, but would be glad if somebody could point me to some more documentation on this.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Reported it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/278842512